# Java compare list with map and output result

Tags: java, list, dictionary, tostring

I need  create a List books and map awards. My goal is go trough list and look

```
The book “<book name>” by <book author> which sold <times published> copies,
received <award for this book> award
```

if Book list author is equal to map Shakespeare == Shakespeare then output

```
The book "Romeo and Juliet" by Shakespeare which sold 4500 copies,
received Too much drama award.
```

Otherwise

```
The book "Romeo and Juliet" by Shakespeare which sold 4500 copies,
received no award
```

I'm new in Java and my trouble is how to send to toString new award parametr when looping and comparing list

My book class

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {

    private String author;
    private String name;
    private int timesPublished;

    public Book(String author, String name, int timesPublished) {
        this.author = author;
        this.name = name;
        this.timesPublished = timesPublished;
    }

    public int getTimesPublished() {
        return timesPublished;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //@Override
    public int compareTo(Book compareBook) {
        if (this.getTimesPublished() == compareBook.getTimesPublished()) {
            return this.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(compareBook.getName().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            return this.getTimesPublished() - compareBook.getTimesPublished();
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("The book \"%s\" by %s which sold %s copies", name, author, timesPublished);
    }

}
```

My main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> awards = new HashMap<String, String>();
    awards.put("Shakespeare", "Too much drama");
    awards.put("Swift", "Survival guide");
    awards.put("Austen", "Did not read");
    awards.put("Dumas", "Sweet revenge");

    List<Book> list = new LinkedList<Book>();

    list.add(new Book("Dumas", "The Count of Monte Cristo", 1245));
    list.add(new Book("Shakespeare", "Romeo and Juliet", 4500));
    list.add(new Book("Austen", "Pride", 1000));
    list.add(new Book("Swift", "Aulliver", 1000));
    list.add(new Book("Tolstoy", "Best", 1000));

    Collections.sort(list);

    for(Book temp: list) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't pass arguments to `toString()`.  You will need to either make the awards part of your `Book` object (which doesn't make sense from an object model perspective), or combine with awards outside of the class.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz OP is linking award to the author, not the book itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a getter for the author variable in the book class. You need this method because the variable is private and inaccessible outside of the class unless you create a getter for the variable like so

```
public String getAuthorName()
{
    return author;
}
```

Then when you print the output you can do the following to check for the author in your map and if [you get back null](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) you know the award doesn't exist otherwise you grab what's in your awards map

```
for(Book temp: list) {
    String awardName = awards.get(temp.getAuthorName());//use the getter to see what the current book's author is
    System.out.println(temp + " received " + (awardName == null ? "no" : awardName) + " award");
}
```

Comment: Nice sample ! working! I'm new in java as I already mention so thank you very much for code sample

Comment: no problem, here is a link to the ternary operator i used in the println (? : ) https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018